# a:visited used with an adjacent sibling operator (+)

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a problem with code given below - is it possible to modify styling of a sibling of an element using :visited? Or maybe in JS it is possible somehow?

Here is a codepen that I'm working on: https://codepen.io/kuba-pisula/pen/MWBYaXX

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <a
    href="https://www.google.com"
    class="link"
    ></a>
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="title" >
      test
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.container {
  &:has(> a:visited) {
    background-color: red;
    h2 {
      color: brown !important;
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
.container {
   a:visited + .content {
     background-color: red;
    h2 {
      color: brown;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: since you are using `:has` can I ask what's the browser you are using to visit the page? Probably that's not the actual problem but it was worth touching the topic. This is the browser compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility .. anyway mostly chromium >=105 only support it (and recently the latest of Safari and Opera.. but not Firefox for example)

Comment: I need it to work on all Chrome/Safari/Firefox. But at least on one is good for me. I've tried it on Chrome and Firefox latest versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting will not work [due to privacy concerns](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/).

> If you use a sibling selector (combinator) like `:visited + span` then the `span` will be styled as if the link were unvisited.